# What determines if a packet should be routed locally or forwarded?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, nftables

[image: Linux packet flow]

As seen in the diagram, when the Linux kernel receives a packet, it goes through the prerouting chain, and then a routing decision is made on whether to forward it to somewhere else or deliver it to a local process.

- How do the IP addresses of the input interface affect the routing decision?
- How do the IP addresses of the other interfaces affect the routing decision?
- How does the routing table affect the routing decision?
- Are there any good resources that describe how the kernel makes this inbound routing decision?

What I am trying to achieve is to get packets from eno1 with destination 95.123.123.62 forwarded into virbr0, which is a `libvirtd` virtual network switch. However, they seem to just be put into the input chain, even though the destination IP belongs to the virbr0 interface. Here is the output of `ip address`:

```
83: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:39:d0:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 95.123.123.62/32 scope global virbr0 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000                                                                                   
    link/ether 30:9c:23:b8:c2:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                                                                                                
    altname enp0s31f6                                                                                                                                                                 
    inet 95.123.123.20/26 brd 95.216.225.63 scope global eno1                                                                                                                         
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the routing table affect the routing decision?

Internally, it's *all* made according to the routing table. Linux has an additional routing table, the `local` table, that has special routes for addresses belonging to the same system:

```
$ ip route ls table local
local 10.147.241.1 dev mlx0 proto kernel scope host
```

Its contents are automatically generated from IP addresses assigned to interfaces. There are *very* few situations where you might want to create such routes or otherwise tweak this table directly, and yours doesn't seem like one – rather, you shouldn't have this address to be assigned to the interface to begin with.

The tables are hooked into the "policy routing" system:

```
$ ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
```

> What I am trying to achieve is to get packets from eno1 with destination 95.123.123.62 forwarded into virbr0, which is a libvirtd virtual network switch. However, they seem to just be put into the input chain, even though the destination ip belongs to the virbr0 interface

That's exactly why the packets go into the input chain – because they belong to a local interface.

Normally, it would be the *other* addresses of the configured subnets – e.g. the entire 192.168.122.0/24 **except** for 192.168.122.1 – that are forwarded through the interface, while the configured address itself is by definition local.

So assigning the address to virbr0 as a /32 has the complete opposite effect than what you're asking for: it indicates that the address is local and therefore by definition not forwarded anywhere further.

If a VM with that address is supposed to be directly connected to the other end of the bridge, you need to add a *route* instead:

```
ip addr del 95.123.123.62/32 dev virbr0
ip route add 95.123.123.62/32 dev virbr0
```

A route without a gateway effectively works like a "local subnet" route – the host will try to ARP for the (virtual) machine having that address.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193669/on-a-router-what-decides-if-a-packet-should-be-forwarded-or-directed-into-the-r) on Unix & Linux, explaining the routing rules. Based on that, it seems like

1. If any interface has the destination IP, the packet is routed to a local process. The IP can belong to a different interface, so that's why it was just routed locally, although it seems a bit weird.
2. Otherwise, the main routing table is used.